# Gradle sync failed after upgrade to Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am being plagued by the below error. Unfortunately I don't have much experience, so I don't have any idea of whats happening.

> gradle sysnc failed : Error:Cause: tried to access method
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V from class
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader

I have tried :

1. Invalidate Caches / restart
2. Synchronize
3. In Settings > gradle > Use Local gradle distribution (changed it from 2.14. to 3.2 to 3.4.1 - to no effect)
4. Build > Clean project then rebuild project

Any ideas or suggestions at this point would help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to settings>Gradle>Select Use default gradle wrapper (recommended) then re-start, cleand and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! Only now I get another error regarding the wrapper...it seems to be a never ending story...

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind of you. This is what the AS event log is saying ':Error:org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forProjectDirectory(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/Appendable;)Lorg/gradle/wrapper/WrapperExecutor;'

Comment: It seems that this error is quite common, but without a solution or at least not every solution works for everyone. Furthermore I am no longer able to start a new project without receiving this error. A bug perhaps?

Comment: Ended up upgrading to the version 2.3.1 - solved most problems but now introduced others.....more to study...